# Android TextView setText apply to all same ResID

Tags: java, android

this is my class that extend RelativeLayout and will populate an linear layout:

```
public CageParameterConfigItem(CageParameterConfigActivity context,Cage cage, VariabiliCentralina item)
{
    super(context);

    mainActivity = context;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    inflater.inflate(R.layout.cage_parameter_configurator_item, this, true);

    currentVariabile = item;
    fatherCage = cage;

    nomeMisura = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cage_parameter_config_item_sondaName);
    abilitazione = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cage_parameter_config_item_Abilitazione);
    soglia1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cage_parameter_config_item_soglia1);
    isteresi1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cage_parameter_config_item_isteresi1);
    soglia2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cage_parameter_config_item_soglia2);
    isteresi2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cage_parameter_config_item_isteresi2);
    allarmeMin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cage_parameter_config_item_AllarmMin);
    allarmeMax = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cage_parameter_config_item_AllarmMax);
    salinity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cage_parameter_config_item_salinity);
    salinityText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cage_parameter_config_item_salinity_text);
    if(!currentVariabile.hasCalibration())
    {
        salinity.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        salinityText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    bindData();
}

protected void bindData()
{
    nomeMisura.setText(VariabiliCentralina.TipoSondaToString(currentVariabile.tipoSonda,getContext()));
    abilitazione.setChecked(currentVariabile.parametri.abilitazione);
    soglia1.setText(String.format("%.1f", currentVariabile.parametri.soglia1));
    soglia2.setText(String.format("%.1f", currentVariabile.parametri.soglia2));
    isteresi1.setText(String.format("%.1f", currentVariabile.parametri.isteresi1));
    isteresi2.setText(String.format("%.1f", currentVariabile.parametri.isteresi2));
    allarmeMin.setText(String.format("%.1f", currentVariabile.parametri.allarmeMin));
    allarmeMax.setText(String.format("%.1f", currentVariabile.parametri.allarmeMax));
    salinity.setText(String.format("%d", currentVariabile.parametri.salinity));
}
```

This is the code the populate linear layout from main activity class:

```
protected void populateGrid()
{
    misureContainer.removeAllViews();
    vMisureView.clear();

    CageParameterConfigItem newView;
    for( VariabiliCentralina item : currentCage.vMisure)
    {
        newView = new CageParameterConfigItem(this,currentCage, item);

        misureContainer.addView(newView);
    }
}
```

where misureContainer is the linearLayout.

On sony experia all work fine, but on Nexus 5 when i setText on bind() function, all textView with same resource ID take same value. I can't understand why!
Can you help me?

Comment: Which text views have same values?

Comment: *all textView with same resource ID take same value* -- None of the TextViews here have the same resource ID.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do here - You should be using a ListView and an Adapter

Comment: PrerakSola: which has same resource id take same value
@cricket_007: i populate an linear layout with many CageParameterConfigItem so in each row of linear layout there is textView with same layoutID. i could try with ListView if this is the problem, but in some phone all goes right.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why some phones would work. The code is compiled the same way.

Comment: i see only now, big mistake, i would say EditText not TextView

Comment: @cricket_007 i just try with listView and it bit more slow than linearlayout but works on both phone. Only strange thing, i suppose phone bug: on first start getView of arrayAdapter class after first item, position change correctly but proposed View return always the same, so i have to make other check to know when recreate it.